# Sails.js and Mocha, res.view testing

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js

I write test for my sails application, but have some problem in controller. When user signup I check for duplication, if yes - render form with error, if no - render form with success message. So can anyone know how to test it right? Or maybe you can suggest better code structure, thanks a lot.

Controller :

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
  if(err) return res.json(err)
  if(!user) { 
    User.create({email:req.body.email, password:req.body.password}).exec(function createCB(err, user){
      if(err) return res.json(err);
      res.view('signup', { message: 'Done, user created'})
    })
  } else 
    res.view('signup', { message: 'User already exist'})
})
```

Test :

```
it('should show error if duplicated user - TODO', function (done) {
  request(sails.hooks.http.app)
    .post('/signup')
    .send({ email: 'test@test.te', password: 'test' })
    .expect(200)
    .end(done)
})
```

So question is, how can I test res.view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use simple request at my test if I want to test my view. Like this:

```
it('able to test view', function(done) {
  require('request-promise')('http://localhost:1337/')
    .then(function(res) {
      res.should.contains('Done, user created');
      done();
    })
    .catch(done);
});
```

It will check the whole body, is there any match string that we provide. Remember to do `npm install request-promise --save-dev` first (or any relevant library that can make request).

Or you can use `supertest` library as mentioned by [@Yann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215167/yann-bertrand) like this

```
it('should be able to test view', function(done) {
  require('supertest')
    .agent(sails.hooks.http.app)
    .post('/signup')
    .send({ email: 'test@test.te', password: 'test' })
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.should.contains('Done, user created');
      return done();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can also try [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) instead of request-promise

Comment: @YannBertrand can you give an example how to use simple request with supertest and get it's HTML body? Because I can't. I'll edit my answer later.

Comment: I'll post that in another answer 'cause code presentation does not fit

Comment: You can copy it, i'll remove both the answer and these comments ;-)

Comment: thanks, I like variant with supertest, all works great :)

Comment: @TolyaDouble choose one answer to prevent misleading that this topic is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to do an HTTP request:

```
it('should be able to test view', function(done) {
  require('supertest')
    .agent(sails.hooks.http.app)
    .post('/signup')
    .send({ email: 'test@test.te', password: 'test' })
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.should.contains('Done, user created');
      return done();
    });
});
```